# Weird RGB value from java BufferedImage getRGB()

Tags: java, image-processing, colors

Im trying to get RGB value from a grayscale image and it was return wrong(?) RGB value. Here is the code.

```
Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(0, 0));
System.out.print(color.getRed());
System.out.print(color.getGreen());
System.out.print(color.getBlue());
```

At a color picker was using, the first pixel RGB value `R:153,G:153,B:153` but my code print

```
203203203
```

Why this thing happened? And also, im trying to use MATLAB Grayscale values for the exact pixel is also 153. Am i doing this wrong?

this is the image

[image]

Comment: @FastSnail here is my grayscale image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWz7hgjG3VEUmhZdWlCYmdVQVk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `image.getRGB(x, y)` by definition returns ARGB values in *sRGB colorspace*.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)):

> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (`TYPE_INT_ARGB`) and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this default model does not match the image `ColorModel`.

Matlab and other tools likely use a linear RGB or gray color space, and this is why the values are different.

You can get the same values from Java if the image is gray scale (`TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`), by accessing the `Raster` and its `getDataElements` method.

```
Object pixel = raster.getDataElements(0, 0, null); // x, y, data array (initialized if null)
```

If the image is `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`, `pixel` will be a `byte` array with a single element.

```
int grayValue = ((byte[]) pixel)[0] & 0xff;
```

This value will be `153` in your case.

Comment: Sir, may I ask you why we need the 0xff mask at the end? I realized that without it, a totally different value appears...

Comment: @Peter Because byte is a signed type in Java, and we want an unsigned value.

Answer (score 4):

Just try this

```
System.out.println(image.getRaster().getSample(0, 0, 0));  //R
System.out.println(image.getRaster().getSample(0, 0, 1));  //G
System.out.println(image.getRaster().getSample(0, 0, 2));  //B
```

Here

```
getSample(int x, int y, int b)
```

Returns the sample in a specified band for the pixel located at (x,y) as an int. [According to [this]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

**Parameters:**
x - The X coordinate of the pixel location
y - The Y coordinate of the pixel location
b - The band to return
 b = [0,1,2] for [R,G,B]

and also take a look at [BufferedImage getRGB vs Raster getSample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821915/bufferedimage-getrgb-vs-raster-getsample)

Comment: I have seen an edit suggest to add import java.awt.image.WritableRaster. getRaster() is a public method in BufferedImage class which returns a WritableRaster object. Why did you suggest the edit? Can you explain a little more? @HawasKaPujaari